# Docker-compose - no space left on device

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am running Docker on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance, and after I run `sudo docker-compose build` and `sudo docker-compose up` I get this error:

`Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-7.so.1: no space left on device`

I did a cleanup using `sudo docker system prune -a`; however, the error persists.

Here's the data after I run `df -h /var/lib/docker/`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.5G  201M  98% /
```

And here's `df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              486736       0    486736   0% /dev
tmpfs             100212     816     99396   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       8065444 7843868    205192  98% /
tmpfs             501056       0    501056   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             501056       0    501056   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         56832   56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1         34176   34176         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop2         33152   33152         0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2996
/dev/loop3        128896  128896         0 100% /snap/docker/471
/dev/loop4        100352  100352         0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop5         56832   56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop6        100736  100736         0 100% /snap/core/10823
/dev/loop7        134784  134784         0 100% /snap/docker/796
tmpfs             100208       0    100208   0% /run/user/1000
```

How can I overcome this problem? Would I be able to increase disk space?

Comment: Your image may need more spaces. Try freeing up more spaces and then try again.

Comment: How can I free up space? Would I have to mess with `/dev/xvda1`?

Comment: What "docker image ls" say?

Comment: You can [resize the EBS volume then extend the filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase your disk size for docker. Check your status with `docker system df` Also you can clean your volumes with prune `docker system prune --volumes`

Comment: Cleaning up my volumes did free up the required space. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an ebs disk volume and mount it under /var/lib/docker. That will solve your disk space problem with docker